# Align block element to the right in a table cell

Tags: css

[image]

In the "Quantidade" column of my shopping cart, which is displayed in a table, everything is aligned to the right except for the error message generated by the jQuery Validation plugin. It's a label element which I'm displaying as "block":

```
td label.error{
    text-align:right;
    display:block;
    width:155px;
}
```

The cell's HTML:

```
<td>
    <input class="required digits valorTotal itensTotal disponivel pesoTotal error" type="text" size="3" maxlength="3" value="1" name="qtd578">
    <label class="error" for="qtd578" generated="true">Não tem tantos itens disponíveis</label>
</td>
```

If I get rid of the fixed width, it aligns to the right as expected, but the reason I'm using a fixed width is because I want the error message text to break and be somewhat compact underneath the text field. I also tried floating the label to the right, but that caused the text field to move to the left of it.

I'm guessing that what I'm trying to do may not be possible with CSS, but I thought that someone might think of a workaround.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the `margin-left` of your element to the `auto`:

```
td label.error {
    margin-left: auto;
    text-align: right;
    display: block;
    width: 155px;
}
```